# One Vector to DataFrame for use in ggplot histogram in R

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to convert ONLY ONE vector into a data frame. I will end up using the data frame for ggplot to create a histogram of frequencies. Here is what I have so far...

```
library(ggplot2)

#This is my vector for prime numbers
prime <- c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97)

#In order to convert it to a data frame, I tried this method
data <- data.frame(numbers=1:100,prime)

#This is the title of my histogram
main <-"Frequency of Prime Numbers"

#This is what I tried to use to plot the histogram
ggplot(data, aes(x=numbers)) +  geom_histogram() +ggtitle(main)
```

I am able to generate a plot of frequencies for these prime numbers, but the frequencies read at a count of 3 and 4, whereas the prime numbers should be reading at a frequency of 1 and everything else should be reading at a frequency of 0.

I think I might be converting my vector to a data frame incorrectly, but I can't seem to figure out how else to convert only ONE vector. I've seen multiple questions regarding converting two vectors or a list with two variables, etc. but nothing on simply one vector...

I guess my question pertains to how I'm converting the vector into a data frame first. Is that correct? If so, why is my plot reading counts of 3 and 4 instead of the prime numbers at frequencies of 1?

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not totally clear on your question, but do you want to have something like `freq <- rep(0, 100); freq[prime] <- 1`

Comment: @Pascal, the frequency of each prime number is 1, but the plot is not showing that. Instead, the plot shows frequencies of 3 and 4 which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Use argument `binwidth` of function `geom_histogram` to adjust the size of the bins, i.e. `binwidth = 1`.

Comment: @Pascal, I tried that, and now it makes all of the numbers at a frequency of 1, not just the prime numbers..

Comment: Yes, becausey you want 100 values of "prime", but the actual length is 25. So they are recycled. That is why you get 3 or 4 as frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

prime <- c(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97)

data <- as.data.frame(prime)

main <-"Frequency of Prime Numbers"

ggplot(data, aes(x=prime)) +  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + ggtitle(main)
```

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean by the values get recycled. Thank you for your help!